# Magento Recurring Billing Solutions

Tags: magento, billing, recurring

Magento is a great product but out-of-the-box it really lacks recurring billing support. I've come to a crossroads with my current project and need some direction.

We have exhausted every Google search and module that is under the sun for Magento to support recurring billing the way we need it to. So far, all we have come across is one module that costs $300 by aHeadWorks in the UK. We've tried the module and are extremely disappointed so far, mainly just due to total lack of support and documentation; Nobody seems to have the knowledge to answer our questions, or even attempt to.

Our goals are simple and we cannot figure out why there aren't more solutions out there to do this, so the question becomes, what is everyone else doing?

All we need to do is the following:

1. Provide subscriptions for items such as web hosting, text message marketing, etc.
2. Tie into our merchant account and authorize.net
3. Keep the customer on our site at all times

Skrill Moneybookers & their module isn't compatible with what we need to do (at least in the US). PayPal sucks and wants to hold our money back and also wants to redirect customers to their site to setup a billing agreement. iTransact services are fantastic but there is one module that is 2 years+ old and has no support.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your recurring billing issue?

Comment: I am no longer a dev on this project, so no but thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: I think https://all4coding.com/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html is the extension you are looking for. It is an enhance of Magento Recurring Payments. And it is also compatible with your requirements. This extension is support PayPal Pro, PayPal Express, Payfow Pro, Payflow Express, etc. They do offer a free trial so you can test it out before you decide to purchase. The best part of this extension is they allow you to define different prices for different subscription periods for the same product which Aheadwork SARP can't. Hope you will find your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the service [OrderGroove.com](http://www.OrderGroove.com).  They specialize in recurring orders in e-commerce systems like Magento.

Comment: While we aren't using OrderGroove (they start at $20k a month) we've gone this direction and hope to have better results. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

The answer is recurring billing is quite a taboo in the e-commerce industry. This is mostly because the big boys, i.e. Mastercard and Visa have very strict rules governing recurring billing transactions.

Recurring billing means storing a customer's credit/debit card data, long number, expiry, and cvv2, for future processing. However, this opens up a huge can of worms in terms of security. This is why Visa/Mastercard impose rules on merchants in becoming PCIDSS compliant. Practically this means your server/website have to be certified to be secure, using a service like McAfee PCIDSS, which basically scans your server/website remotely and attempts to break it. It looks for open ports, badly configured firewall (or lack of), xss scripting flaws, mysql injection breaches, operating system security breaches, and many more. One of the most important elements with PCIDSS is having all card data encrypted.

It is a laborious process, since once you are given a report, you are also expected to repair all flagged critical issues and pass the scan. There are other steps to complete, but I shan't enumerate them all here. See the pci dss website for reference. You are also expected to keep the certification up-to-date on a quarterly basis.

Basically what this means is that Visa/Mastercard don't particularly like the smaller merchants to have this feature, as they can be of major risk to clients. If their system is breached, hackers could use the card data for criminal enterprises.

This in turn means Visa/Mastercard favor the big players in the industry to handle recurring billing, such as PayPal, Worldpay, authorize.net, etc. One port of call, one entity to fine and recover losses if there's a problem.

And now we return to Magento. Whilst it is relatively easy to create a normal payment method in Magento, since most PSPs work in the same manner [mostly], recurring billing is handled differently from provider to provider. Furthermore, some are more restrictive than others.

**I can't and won't recommend PayPal as I have had extremely bad experiences with them, I can definitely recommend Worldpay + Futurepay + Invisible XML method. You would need to hire a Magento developer to write a custom module for you, but it's doable. I am currently writing a module for a client in Norway using a norwegian payment method and recurring billing.**

If you still need help, get in touch, I can write a module for your store.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Michael.

Answer (score 5):

Paradox Labs has an Authorize.NET CIM extension that supports Magento Recurring Profiles and Braintree recently released an extension that also supports them. I have made lots of improvements to Magento's recurring profiles. You can definitely tell they are in beta form, but that should stop you from getting your hands dirty and finishing things that the Magento team hasn't got to yet.

Here are a few things I improved:

https://github.com/tegansnyder/Magento-Recurring-Beta-Grid-Improvements

https://github.com/tegansnyder/Magento-Programmatically-Create-Recurring-Profiles-Authorize.net-CIM

https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder

I'm had to make modifications to the cart controller to allow discount codes to display on the frontend when used on nominal items. By default they wouldn't display that they were applied.

I also had to make some modifications to the daily billing job that runs to remove the discounts the second time the profile is billed. Magento was applying them each time it reached the end of cycle.

Lots of little things here and there, but it's getting there.

Comment: That's pretty funny you mention that. I actually interviewed to work there about 3 weeks ago. They are about 3 blocks away from where I work now :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do.  Could you tell me which file needs to be edited to remove discounts from recurring items after their initial sale?

Answer (score 3):

There are different strategies to implement recurring billing / product subscriptions with Magento:

**Magento Recurring Profiles**

Magento's built in recurring profiles feature can be used with compatible Magento payment extensions and gateways.  These include PayPal, Authorize.Net CIM (Customer Information Manager).  A payment extension which supports the recurring profiles feature is required for this approach, for example [Paradox Labs CIM Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/authorize-net-cim-with-recurring-profiles.html).

**Customize Magento to Support Recurring Billing**

This can be done with a third party extension, like the ([AheadWorks SARP extension](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html)) or developed from scratch.

**Integrate External Subscription Management Software**

Platforms which specialize in eCommerce product subscriptions include:

- [Subscribe Pro](http://www.subscribepro.com/)
- [Order Groove](http://www.ordergroove.com/)

Some subscription management software for digital goods includes:

- [Recurly](http://recurly.com/)
- [Zuora](http://www.zuora.com/)